# How to change FROM field in SharePoint designer workflow - 'Send Mail' activity

Tags: workflow

I work with SharePoint Online and SharePoint Designer 2013. Is it possible to change FROM address in workflow email notification? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible with the Send Email activity in a SharePoint Designer workflow.